# CodeIgniter 4 CI_ENVIRONMENT set to development gives "No direct script access allowed" error

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I am trying to change the environment of my CI4 project to development.
I changed the value in the .env file and removed the "#",but when I do so I am greeted with a "No direct script access allowed" error.

I tried changing it to testing as well but then I get the following message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Tests\Support\Log\TestLogger' not
> found

The CI4 version we are currently using is one of the earlier versions that was released but we did update the files to a more recent version a while ago.

Could this error be caused by an incomplete older version of CodeIgniter?
There are quite a lot of thing we changed to make it work initially so if we need to move it to a newer version it might take some time and move us further behind schedule.
But if this is the only thing that will work then we will need to do so.

I renamed the 'Errors' view file to see if I can skip the "No direct script access allowed" message, but then I get an error message because it cannot find the view.

Is it safe to remove the following line from the error views?

> defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

Thank you for any help you can provide

Comment: What do you mean by "here are quite a lot of thing we changed to make it work initially"? Did you change core files? If so you should avoid doing that and upgrade to the latest CI4 version.
Therefore, `defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');` is not used anymore in CI4. It might be some CI3 legacy you have here

Comment: The version of CI the project was in was the alpha version of CI4 or maybe one of the versions just after that, it was our first time using CI4 back then so we did not really know what to do. The stuff that needed to be changed was things like the .htaccess file and other general files, we did not change anything in the core files

Comment: Issue has however been resolved by switching to CI 4.0.4, but base_url() works slightly different so we had to update it on all 400 occurrences throughout the project

Comment: did u delete (app/view/errors) folder ? do not delete that

Comment: No folders or files were deleted, issue was resolved when I switched to a newer version of CI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved by changing the project to CodeIgniter 4.0.4.
We still have to update a lot of the php from how this version differs from the alpha version, but I do believe all the issues have been resolved.